# Url smart redirect regex

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im having troubles in the "domain.com" url format related to my API calls. Mostly, calls in "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" are generating different sessions values.

What I need is to redirect the user to the right url if the url is "domain.com/a/b/" to "www.domain.com/a/b/", including the root folder.

I do have a master page, and Im probaly going to check the url in the page load.

Problems:

1. What is the regex to match the "www" in "http://www.domain.com/a/b/c/"?
2. Should I use a insert to fix the url?

   ```
       string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
       if (Regex.Match(url, @"http://(www).com/.*").Success)
       {
           Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
           Response.AddHeader("Location", url.Insert(8, "www");
       }
   ```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `.BeginsWith("http://www")` and `.BeginsWith("https://www")`?  Regex seems overly complicated for this use.

Comment: Its not what I asked. Thank you anyways.

Comment: You will probably not get any additional answers, unless you can state way you need to use regex.  Most programmers prefer to use a shovel to dig a whole for a mailbox instead of using a backhoe.